# Passport expiration policy inside EU for EU residents

Tags: schengen, passports, eu, spanish-residents

Just remarked that my passport is expiring on 23rd Jan 2020, there is no way I can travel outside EU seen the 6 months passport validity policy for most of the countries.

I'm resident of Spain, and thinking about spending the New year in Athens, is there any similar 6 months policy or my passport counts valid with my Spanish residency card ?

Comment: I suppose you've considered getting your passport replaced and found that it's not possible to do it in one week?

Comment: @phoog right, the moroccan consulate can issue a new one in 2 weeks, and I learned that temporary passport doesn't exist, even if they claim so in the gov website

Comment: @Willeke I'm a non-EU citizen with a spanish residency card

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the trip as long as you return to Spain while your passport is still valid. There is no extra passport validity requirement for internal Schengen travel.  To avoid complications, you should probably avoid itineraries that require a layover outside the Schengen area.

The Schengen area has a requirement for short-term visitors that passports be valid for three months beyond the anticipated departure from the Schengen area.  But this is enforced only on entry into the Schengen area, so it does not apply to you.  Furthermore, while you are a short-term visitor to Greece, you are not a short-term visitor to the Schengen area.

Comment: Lastly, the three-month requirement doesn't apply at all to Schengen residents, even at the external border